# Camera, Microphone and Audio/Video storage permission for ios app

Tags: ios, swift4.2, xcode10.2

I want to make a video recording app, thats why i need camera, microphone and storage permission. in my info.plist, I add camera , microphone and photos permission. The problem is here, when app opens, it needs permission. It wants camera and microphone permission and after few minutes it wants photo permission.

```
class UserPermission: NSObject {



    //check camera and microphone is granted
    func checkAllPermissionGranted() -> Bool{
        print("photo permission: \(checkPhotoLibraryPermission())")
        if(checkCameraAccess() && checkMicrophoneAccess() && checkPhotoLibraryPermission()){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }


    //    //storage access permission
    func checkPhotoLibraryPermission() -> Bool {
        var isPermited: Bool = false
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            //handle authorized status
            isPermited = true
            break
        case .denied, .restricted :
            //handle denied status
            isPermited = false
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            // ask for permissions
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
                switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    // as above
                    isPermited = true
                    break
                case .denied, .restricted:
                    // as above
                    isPermited = false
                    break
                case .notDetermined:
                    // won't happen but still
                    isPermited = false
                    break
                @unknown default:
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        @unknown default:
            print("error")
        }

        return isPermited
    }

    //microphone access permission
    func checkMicrophoneAccess() -> Bool {
        var  isparmited = false

        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission  {
        case .denied:
            print("Denied, request permission from settings")
        //presentPhoneSettings()
        case .granted:
            print("Authorized, proceed")
            isparmited = true
        case .undetermined:
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { success in
                if success {
                    print("Permission granted, proceed")
                    isparmited = true
                } else {
                    print("Permission denied")
                    isparmited = false
                }
            }
        @unknown default:
            print("error")
        }
        return isparmited
    }


    //camera access permission
    func checkCameraAccess() -> Bool {
        var  isparmited = false
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .denied:
            print("Denied, request permission from settings")
        //presentPhoneSettings()
        case .restricted:
            print("Restricted, device owner must approve")
            isparmited = false
        case .authorized:
            print("Authorized, proceed")
            isparmited = true
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { success in
                if success {
                    print("Permission granted, proceed")
                    isparmited = true
                } else {
                    print("Permission denied")
                    isparmited = false
                }
            }
        @unknown default:
            print("error")
        }
        return isparmited
    }

}
```

but, I need these permission one by one, like first wants camera then microphone and then photos but not with delay of last one(photos). help me please.

Comment: with the code you have shown us we can't help

Comment: @Lu_, because of my lower reputation, image of info.plist could not here. but i have added code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some kind tutorial collectionView and each cell could contain a description for permission with button to fire a system permission.